# Remove setError from EditText xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

Hi I know this question is asked before, but I'm facing a different issue. I want to dismiss the setError from editText. but the following does not work for me,

```
editText.setError(null);
```

It's expecting the other argument which is the drawable icon. I'm using visual studio xamarin android with C#.

Any help is greatly appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xamarin version only has the method that takes the text and icon. As the [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Widget.TextView.SetError/p/Java.Lang.ICharSequence/Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable/) says you can clear the error by making the text `null` and the icon should also be `null` in this case. So just use

```
editText.SetError((string)null, null);
```

The casting to `string` will make it clear to the compiler which method to use. In this case it doesn't matter.

Comment: I already tried this. Doesn't work for me, I get this error ""The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: TextView.SetError(ICharSequesnce, Drawable) and 'TextView.SetError(string, Drawable)'

Comment: @KMR Added how to handle that

Comment: Perfect, Works like a charm. Thanks you so much